# Remove old unused Joomla files after upgrading to 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I upgraded a Joomla site from 1.6.5 to 2.5 successfully.
However, the webhost company found at least one file that seems to belong to the old version (libraries/joomla/version.php).

The file contains :

```
 public $RELEASE    = '1.6';
```

So, I removed that file.

My question : **How can I verify that there are no other old files left after the update?** That webhost company is super picky and wants to make sure that there is absolutely no trace left of the old Joomla version (apparently this would cause a major a security treat, bla bla bla...).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Joomla updates, if I'm not mistaken, all files/folders that are no longer used are deleted.

In you're case, this is a very odd file to still have lurking around.

At a guess, I think it might be due to the fact that the correct process for migration would be as follows:

```
1.6 >> 1.7 >> 2.5
```

whereas you went straight from 1.6 to 2.5

**If** you still have a backup of your 1.6 website, I would suggest trying the above process

Comment: I did follow the upgrade process 1.6 >> 1.7 >> 2.5, very strange indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 2.x has less files than 1.x.
I think the best solution is to compare 1.x and 2.x all files with a compare tool and delete them manually.